# Using Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Having problem getting fragment showing correctly on device. I have a frame on an activity and a Frame on a Fragment. Trying to do a replace frame on activity with frame from Fragment. however what I am getting is Frame on activity being smushed together and fragment frame underneath on display.

Here is code calling the Fragment.

```
    public void setupMultiItems(String mScan){
    Timber.d("Multiple matching Items");

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("valuesArray",mScan);
    SelectItemFragment fragobj = new SelectItemFragment();
    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction  = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentFrame,  fragobj);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Here is XML for the activity.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGray"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_select_item"
    tools:context="com.procatdt.stockright.activities.PutAwayAreaActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

       >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include2"
            layout="@layout/frm1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FragmentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/layout_numpad5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="220dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
           />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is XML for the fragment.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.procatdt.stockright.activities.SelectItemFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/newFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSelectItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Select Item" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

all the controls on activity are being shrunk and jammed together with the button from the fragment showing underneath.

Any help on what I am missing.
My background has been in VB for last 18 years. This is my first Android Studio Java project and have been muddling by getting hung up on fragments.

Comment: Try removing the innermost FrameLayout in your fragments XML, it seems redundant.

Also, try using getSupportFragmentManager instead.

And include a tag in your call to .replace()

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager isn't available. Should I change my imports. I am currently using                                                                                                      import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably have to change your imports

Comment: how would I use the tag in the .replace call